# Elasticsearch - queries throttle cpu

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

Recently our cluster has seen extreme performance degradation.  We had 3 nodes, 64 GB, 4CPU (2 core) each for an index that is 250M records, 60GB large.  Performance was acceptable for months.

Since then we've:
1. Added a fourth server, same configuration.
2. Split the index into two indexes, query them with an alias
3. Disable paging (windows server 2012)
4. Added synonym analysis on one field

Our cluster can now survive for a few hours before it's basically useless.  I have to restart elastic on each node to rectify the problem.  We tried bumping each node to 8 cpus (2 cores) with little to no gain.

One issue is that EVERY QUERY uses up 100% of the cpu of whatever node it hits.  Every query is facetted on 3+ fields, which hasn't changed since our cluster was healthy.  Unfortunately I'm not sure if this was an happening before, but certainly it seems like an issue.  We need to be able to respond to more than one request every few seconds obviously.  When multiple requests come in at the same time the performance doesn't seem to get worse for those particular responses.  Again, over time, the performance slows to a crawl; the CPU (all cores) stays maxed out indefinitely.

I'm using elasticsearch 1.3.4 and the plugin elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic 2.3.0 on every box and have been even when our performance wasn't so terrible.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

it seems like the performance issue is due to index aliasing.  When I pointed the site to a single index that ultimately stores about 80% of the data, the CPU wasn't being throttled.  There were still a few 100% spikes, but they were much shorter.  When I pointed it back to the alias (which points to two indexes total), I could literally bring the cluster down by refreshing the page a dozen times quickly: CPU usage goes to 100% every query and gets stuck there with many in a row.

Is there a known issue with elastic search aliases?  Am I using the alias incorrectly?

**UPDATE 2:**

Found the cause in the logs. Paging queries are TERRIBLE.  Is this a known bug in elastic?  If I run an empty query then try and view the last page (from 100,000,000 e.g.) it brings the whole cluster down.  That SINGLE QUERY.  It gets through the first 1.5M results then quits, all the while taking up 100% of the CPU for over a minute.

**UPDATE 3:**
So here's somethings else strange.  Pointing to an old index on dev (same size, no aliases) and trying to reproduce the paging issue; the cluster doesn't get hit immediately.  It has 1% cpu usage for the first 20 seconds after the query.  The query returns with an error before the CPU usage every goes up.  About 2 minutes later, CPU usage spikes to 100% and server basically crashes (can't do anything else because CPU is so over taxed).  On the production index this CPU load is instantaneous (it happens immediately after a query is made)

Answer (score 0):

Without checking certain metrics it is very difficult to identify the cause of slow response or any other issue. But from the data you have mentioned it looks like there are to many cache evictions happening thereby increasing the number of Garbage Collection on your nodes. A frequent Garbage Collection (mainly the old GC) will consume lot of CPU. This in turn will start to affect all cluster.

As you have mentioned it started giving issues only after you added another node. This surprises me. Is there any increase in the traffic?.

Can you include the output of _stats API taken at the time when your cluster slows down. It will have lot of information from which I can make a better diagnosis. Also include a sample of the query.

I suggest you to install [bigdesk](https://github.com/lukas-vlcek/bigdesk) so that you can have a graphical view of your cluster health more easily.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of young gc messages when the cluster gets stuck at 100% and right before.  I think gc is definitely using up the cpu, but what's the cause? Per my update I believe it's the use of aliases.

Comment: It is unlikely that aliases will cause CPU throttling. And same for young GC. Do post the result of _stats api when/after issue happens. You can look for total GC count, total cache eviction, cache memory etc. if it is related to memory issue certain fixes can be done.